# Making the grouped row editable in angular-slickgrid

Tags: angular, slickgrid

While implementing angular-slickgrid, I have a requirement to make the grouped row (Formatter: sum for the children rows of a group) editable, and then pass the value to the children rows of the group. 
How do I achieve this, while keeping the references same?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular-slickgrid, but I can tell you that this is going to require a significant degree of customisation of the grid. You'll need to work out how to make the sum row editable (given that it has no data row behind it), and it would be easiest to create or use an existing event on that row to loop through the data and make changes to rows matching the group.

Comment: I am able to make the row editable, capture the event and get the rows in that group, but the problem lies in keeping the reference same.
I have to inject HTML and script as a string to do the task, but while passing I have to parse the rows as a string, which messes up the reference

Comment: can you post some code for the bit you're having trouble with? it's quite hard to visualise

Comment: putting it in the answers section

Answer (score 0):

```
groupByDurationEffortDrivenPercent() {
    // ${GroupTotalFormatters.sumTotals(g.totals,columns[6])}
    var columns=this.columnDefinitions
    this.dataviewObj.setGrouping([
      {
        getter: 'duration',
        formatter: function(g){

          let ff= JSON.stringify(g.rows)
          let tester=89

          return `Duration:  ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span><div onclick='x=dissagregate(${ff},this);console.log(x)' class="slick-cell l7 r7">${GroupTotalFormatters.sumTotals(g.totals,columns[6])}</div> 
          <script>
              function dissagregate(x,z,y){
                child=x[0]
                child['cost']=200

                old_value=  parseFloat(y.innerText)

                if(isNaN(old_value)){

                }
                else{

                  var html="<input type='text' value='" + old_value + "' onblur='changeinput(this)'  >"
                  y.removeChild(y.firstChild)
                  y.innerHTML=html


                }
                return x;
               }

              function changeinput(ele){
                var parent= ele.parentNode
                var val = ele.value;
                parent.innerText=val
              }


          </script>

          `;
        },
        aggregators: [
          new Aggregators.Sum('duration'),
          new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
        ],
        aggregateCollapsed: true,
        lazyTotalsCalculation: false,
        displayTotalsRow:false

      },
```

Comment: I want to modify g.rows through the script

Comment: first of all, this should not be an answer, it should be part of your question. Second of all, you should never insert script like that, this is so so dangerous security wise. The `formatter` should be a string and only a string that is only meant to display the group title. I don't think SlickGrid group formatter are editable, so as @Ben said, this would require lots of customization.